# For which parameter is the matrix diagonalizable? and finding the diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I am not sure about my answer. I have found similar questions to mine but they still did not help me.

I have this matrix, and I need to find the values of $a$ parameter where $D$ will be Diagonalizable:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}0& a&-a \\a&0&a\\ -a & a &0\end{pmatrix}=D.$$

I have found that $p(x)= (x-a)^2(x+2a),$
so my answer is as follows.

When $a=0$,
my Eigenvalues $0$ and the diagonal matrix =  $diag(0,0,0),$ 
so the matrix is diagonalizable.

When $a$ any real number and not $0$, it is also diagonalizable, and its  diagonal matrix = $diag(a,a,-2a).$

So it means $D$ is diagonalizable for any value of $a$.

am i wrong here?
i just not sure if I answered the question at all, if I covered all the cases.

Comment: Have you checked that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $a$ is $2$?

Comment: yes,, I'm just not sure if I covered all the cases

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Indeed, for all $a\in\mathbb{R}\space,$ $D$ is diagonalizable. This is because $D$ is symmetric for all values of $a\in\mathbb{R}\space,$ and because real symmetric matrices are diagonalizable by a spectral theorem.

Comment: Appreciate it, thank you for you help